# When bisecting, how can specs ordering be inconsistent when using --seed option

Tags: rspec

I'm hunting down flaky (flickering) specs, and running `rspect bisect --seed 19818`

The first checks seems to be promising:

```
Running suite to find failures... (1 minute 6.68 seconds)
 - Failing examples (6) - Failure appears to be order-dependent
```

But then this happens:

```
Round 1: bisecting over non-failing examples 1-299
Bisect failed!      

The example ordering is inconsistent. `--bisect` relies upon consistent ordering (e.g. by passing `--seed` if you're using random ordering) to work properly.
```

Since I'm using explicit `--seed` option, I guess it's not rspec engine that changes the order of the samples. The only thing I can imagine ATM is something like that in specs:

```
if [true,false].sample 
   expect(x).to eq(y)
   expect(a).to eq(b)
else
   expect(a).to eq(b)
   expect(x).to eq(y)
end
```

But it's 300 spec files, so It's not easy to track down.

I assume `[true, false].sample` is not influenced by the rspec seed, if it was - this should return the same result each time. Maybe it's a wrong assumption?

Did anyone stumbled upon such an issue? Is there any other thing that could influence the specs ordering?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 05.11.2020**

I spent some time debugging the "order inconsistent error" by rspec bisect.

I realized there is a bug in the rspec bisect implementatin that occurs when the spec failure you're bisecting is not the last spec in the list you provided.

I documented it more in details in an issue on Github [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2696#issuecomment-721074091).

What you can do to mitigate it is to get the list of the spec in the execution order and remove all successful specs after the failed one you want to debug.

For example you can use rspec dry run to get the list of specs:

```
bin/rspec --seed 19818 --dry-run -f j
```

Then you fetch the spec ids in the order of execution from the resulting json (I may add a command for that later), remove everything that is after the one that has failed and then run the bisect as

```
bin/rspec --order defined --bisect [...your spec list goes here]
```

**Original answer**

Are you specifying `bisect_runner` configuration value anywhere?

I discovered that `The example ordering is inconsistent` error could emerge when `bisect_runner` configuration is different across `rspec` invocations.

For example if your top-level invocation of `rspec --bisect` is setting `bisect_runner` to `:shell` then during the bisect process other instances of `rspec` are being run. If for any reason configuration of `bisect_runner` is changed (e.g. some of your specs are using additional `RSpec.configure` calls and overriding it to `:fork`) then your bisect will fail with the mentioned error.

One possible case of such misconfiguration could be that your top-level `rspec` invocation doesn't require `spec_helper.rb` and uses the default value of `bisect_runner` which is `:fork` while `spec_helper.rb` is overriding it to `:shell` and is required by individual spec files.

In this case try running your `rspec --bisect` command with `--require spec_helper` CLI argument.

Comment: At this point, I have no way to answer your question. Currently the project does not have `bisect_runner` configured anywhere, but I have no idea if that was the case a year ago (it's a project that 100+ devs actively works on). But thanks for the answer - didn't know about `bisect_runner` before. I hope this helps someone (or me in the future).